# Twitter REST API and ruby hashtag confusion

Tags: ruby, rest, twitter

so I'm trying to set up a script to grab tweets so I can use them in my app. Currently I'm using Ruby 2.0.0 and the 1.1 Twitter API REST. Currently I'm not worried about storing the tweets in a database or anything I'm just simply trying to get the correct tweets into terminal. Here is my current code.

```
require 'twitter'

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  config.consumer_secret     = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  config.access_token        = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  config.access_token_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
end

topics = ["#BreakingBad", "#Gameofthones"]
client.filter(:track => topics.join(",")) do |tweet|
    puts tweet.text
endtag = options[:search]
```

My problem is that when I run the script I get flooded with just a mass of tweets in all different languages. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I would also like to say Twitter API is a bit annoying compared to other API's I have used.

Comment: Is the problem that you have too many tweets?  Maybe you want to try client.filter(...).take(25) to limit the number of tweets?

Comment: What is the specific problem you are experiencing?  Are you trying to filter by language?

Comment: Not at all, I'll work all of that later, I'm just trying to get the tweets to be from a specific hashtag, thats all. So all tweets with #BreakingBad; but I've tried using json.parse, i've tried using nokogiri, and other code and i'm getting either errors or just lumps of random tweets.